# Display only the Id's of users who have not added comments for 3 Days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with multiple rows. The first is called `comments` and has the following structure:

```
user_id   last_commented
........................
9239289   2017-11-06
4239245   2017-11-05
4239245   2017-11-03
6239223   2017-11-02
1123139   2017-11-04
```

The second one is called `users` and has the following structure:

```
user_id   user_name   user_status
.................................
9239289   First Name   0
4239245   First Name2  2
6239223   First Name3  1
1123139   First Name4  2
```

I need a query that displays the users who have not added comments for the last 3 days and have a `user_status` equals to 2.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT user_name FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(last_commented) lastdate,user_id
    FROM `comments` 
    GROUP BY user_id
) A 
LEFT JOIN users
USING (user_id)
WHERE lastdate < ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) 
AND user_status = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (
   select 1
   from comments c
   where c.user_id = u.user_id and last_commented > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
) and user_status = 2
```

**EDIT**: if you want the number of days since the last user login in the result then you can use the following approach:

```
select u.*, datediff(DATE(now()), comment.last_commented)
from users u
join (
   select user_id, max(last_commented) last_commented
   from comments
   group by user_id 
) comment on comment.user_id = u.user_id
where last_commented <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

This approach uses subquery to find the last comment date and then it uses it for filtering and also for computation.

Comment: Is there a way that I can display how many days it was since they last commented?

Comment: @DimitarArabadzhiyski you can write subquery to solve it, I will try

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. It displays an empty table

Comment: @DimitarArabadzhiyski I had oposite equation, try it now

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query.

```
SELECT MAX(last_commented) lastdate,user_id
    FROM `comments` 
where lastdate<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 day) and
user_status = 2

    GROUP BY user_id
```